# Como passar todas palavras de um array para maiúsculo usando toUpperCase()?

Tags: javascript, array, string

A função necessita retornar todas as palavras do *array* em maiúsculo.

```
function transformaParaMaiusculo(palavras){

   for (let i=0; i<palavras.lengh; i++){
      palavras.push(palavras[i].toUpperCase())
   }
   return palavras
}

console.log(transformaParaMaiusculo(["arroz", "blusa", "lápis"])
```

Logo que executo o programa, retorna sem estarem maiúsculas.

Answer (score 3):

Se você deseja fazer uma copia do mesmo, você pode usar o [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), exemplo:

```js
var min = ["arroz", "blusa", "lápis"];
var mai = min.map(p => p.toUpperCase());

console.log(mai);
```

A função `map` irá percorrer cada elemento do seu array e retornar um novo array a partir de como você transformou os elementos ao interno da `map`

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar um novo *array* e retorná-lo, está fazendo quase certo, só que não está criando o *array*, está tentando fazer no próprio, isso não faz sentido. usando uma função própria montado a lógica já que isso parece um exercício que testa justamente isso (existem funções prontas, mas não parece ser o que deseja):

```js
function transformaParaMaiusculo(palavras) {
    var novo = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) novo.push(palavras[i].toUpperCase());
    return novo;
}

console.log(transformaParaMaiusculo(["arroz", "blusa", "lápis"]))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/UpperInArray.js).

Por que eu não faço de outro jeito?

O mais importante é que sendo esse um exercício de algoritmo é importante fazer do jeito mais básico possível, da forma que o exercício provavelmente quer, não é da forma que alguém faria com conhecimento mais avançado

Também porque mesmo dando para fazer de forma mais abstrata, a performance do abstrato não é boa e isso pode fazer diferença em alguns casos, ainda que para o caso específico seja secundário, mas é bom alertar porque muitas pessoas leem essas coisas e não entendem que há motivos para fazer de cada jeito.

Daria para usar a própria variável sem usar o *array* novo, mas isso não é o que está no caminho que o exercício estava fazendo, e provavelmente não é o que deseja porque ele mudaria o conteúdo de uma variável que seja passada para essa função.

Answer (score 0):

se você quer transformar o array ao invés de gerar um novo você pode tentar isso aqui:

```
palavras.forEach(palavra => palavra = palavra.toUpperCase());
```

se você quer gerar um novo array  vc pode usar isso aqui:

```
const maiusculas = palavras.map(palavra => palavra.toUpperCase());
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você esta executando `.push(...)` e isso é usado para adicionar um novo item, se o intuito é atualizar os itens existentes basta acessar e aplicar `.toUpperCase()` diretamente, também não há necessidade alguma de criar um novo `array`, a não ser que tenha como intenção fazer uma filtragem mais complexa, mas até o momento não parece o caso, então atualize diretamente assim:

```js
palavras[i] = palavras[i].toUpperCase();
```

Exemplo:

```js
function transformaParaMaiusculo(palavras)
{
    for (let i = 0, j = palavras.length; i < j; i++) {
         palavras[i] = palavras[i].toUpperCase();
    }

    return palavras;
}

console.log(transformaParaMaiusculo(["arroz", "blusa", "lápis"]));
```

Note que coloquei o `palavras.length` na variavel `j`, pro seu código não há ganho de performance, mas se fosse um array gigante poderá sentir uma pequena melhora (não é tão grande, é uma pequena melhora apenas)

Realmente `.map()` aqui também não vai ter vantagens, e nem desvantagem, claro que uma vantagem no futuro seria aplicar um contexto se for uma classe/objeto aplicado ao callback (função):

```
 arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

Assim no `this` teria acesso ao contexto da classe, claro que escrever `.map()` e bem menor que um `for()`, mas se tiver interesse em controlar o indice ou saber em qual esta com um for básico já irá resolver (dá até pra fazer dentro do `.map()`, mas ai envolve entender bem o contexto das variaveis, nenhum é melhor ou pior que o outro, cada um vai lhe servir melhor uma hora.